# Poisson equation on a square

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Studying PDEs from the notes of my professor, and there's a part I don't understand about seeking a solution for the Poisson equation on a square. Let's start from the beginning though. We want to solve the problem 
$$\begin{cases}
 &\nabla^2u=F(x,y) \\ 
 &u(x,0)=a(x) \\ 
 &u(\pi,y)=b(y) \\ 
 &u(x,\pi)=c(x) \\ 
 &u(0,y)=d(y) 
\end{cases}$$
By linearity, we can solve 5 problems distinctly. Among these 5 problems, there's the "seeking a solution for the nonhomogeneous equation". At one point, it says on the notes: We can write $F(x,y)$ as $\sum F_n(y)X_n(x)$, where $X_n(x)$ satisfies the equation $X_n''(x)=-\lambda X_n(x)$. I know he wants to solve it using Lagrange's method, but I don't quite understand why $F(x,y)$ can be written that way. Anyone?

Comment: Are you sure he didn't mean "*If* $F(x, y)$ can be written as [the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$]..."? Because in that case, it's quite common to try to find a solution using separation of variables, by assuming $u(x, y) = X(x)Y(y)$ to reduce the PDE to two ODEs.

Comment: Well, I figured it out eventually. What he did was assuming $F(x,y)$ could be written like that, so we have: $$\sum X''(x)Y(y) + X(x)Y''(y) = \sum F_n(y)X(x)$$, where $F_n(y)=\int_0^π F(x,y)\sin nx dx$. He the equated the terms of the series and solved the two ODEs separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is possible is that the eigenfunctions (the functions that satisfy $X''=-\lambda X$ and the boundary conditions) form a basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$. Therefore, for each $y$ one can expand $F(x,y)$ in this basis; the coefficients become $F_n(y)$.

These coefficients come from integral formulas like $\int_0^\pi F(x,y)X_n(x)\,dx$, so they inherit continuity, or smoothness, from $F$.

But often, a lecturer doesn't have time or inclination to go into the details of existence (what are the function spaces, why is this a basis, etc.), so the exposition becomes "let's assume this is possible, and see what we get".