# How to solve poisson equation on square?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I had read Poisson equation theory . To understand that theory I wanted to solve some basic Poisson equation .

So I constructed following problem

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=1$

$u(0,y)=u(x,0)=u(x,1)=u(1,y)=0$.

I had studied green representation formula. But for this simple looking region say unit square. How to solve this PDE?

Any Help/Hint will be useful.

Comment: Try separation of variables perhaps?

Comment: Related post [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844570/poisson-equation-on-a-square), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295457/poisson-equation-on-unit-square)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\mrm{u}_{xx} + \mrm{u}_{yy} = 1\,,\quad
\mrm{u}\pars{0,y} =\mrm{u}\pars{x,0} =\mrm{u}\pars{x,1}
= \mrm{u}\pars{1,y} = 0}: {\Large ?}}$

---

$\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} \equiv
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{x}\sin\pars{n\pi y}}$ *already* satisfies the boundary condition
$\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,0} = \mrm{u}\pars{x,1} = 0}$.
In addittion, $\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,y}}$ satisfies the above differential equation. Namely,
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{a_{n}''\pars{x} -
\pars{n\pi}^{2}a_{n}\pars{x}}\sin\pars{n\pi y} = 1
$$
Multiply both members by $\ds{\sin\pars{n\pi y}}$ and integrate over
$\ds{y \in \pars{0,1}}$:
\begin{align}
&{1 \over 2}\bracks{a_{n}''\pars{x} - \pars{n\pi}^{2}a_{n}\pars{x}} =
{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n\pi}
\\[2mm] \implies &
a_{n}\pars{x} = -2\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{n\pi}^{3}} +
b_{n}\sinh\pars{n\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - x}} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{n\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - x}}
\end{align}

---

The general solution is reduced to
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} & =
-2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{n\pi}^{3}}\,\sin\pars{n\pi y}
\\[2mm] & +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\braces{b_{n}\sinh\pars{n\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - x}} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{n\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - x}}}\sin\pars{n\pi y}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\mrm{u}\pars{0,y} = 0 \implies
\\[2mm] &
-2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{n\pi}^{3}}\,\sin\pars{n\pi y} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{b_{n}\sinh\pars{n\pi \over 2} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{n\pi \over 2}}\sin\pars{n\pi y} = 0
\\[5mm] & \mrm{u}\pars{1,y} = 0 \implies
\\[2mm] &
-2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{n\pi}^{3}}\,\sin\pars{n\pi y} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{-b_{n}\sinh\pars{n\pi \over 2} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{n\pi \over 2}}\sin\pars{n\pi y} = 0
\end{align}
Adding and subtracting both members of this equations yields
$\ds{b_{n} = 0}$ and
$$
c_{n} = 2\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{n\pi}^{3}}
\mrm{sech}\pars{n\pi \over 2}
$$

---

Finally,
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} & =
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{-\,{4 \over \pi^{3}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi y} \over
\pars{2n + 1}^{3}}}
\\[2mm] & \bbox[10px,#ffd]{+
{4 \over \pi^{3}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\mrm{sech}\pars{\bracks{n + 1/2}\pi} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{3}}
\cosh\pars{\bracks{n + {1 \over 2}}\pi\bracks{1 - 2x}}
\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi y}}
\end{align}

Comment: If it is a rectangle of size a,b , the BC becomes u(0, y) = u(a, y) = u(x, 0) = u(x, b) = 0
What would change in the final answer ?